# Hibernate/SQL SERVER java.sql.SQLException: Cannot insert NULL values into column that has default value

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

having Hibernate and SQL Server, I'm facing a problem when I'd like to update an entity called **Client**. The **Client** entity has auditing fields like the name of current user who create/update this latter and the date times when these operations occurs. The problem here is that when an update happens, the ***java.sql.SQLException*** is thrown, below the log for more details:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'IS_SUPPRIMER', table 'IJSS_DB.dbo.TF_CODE_PAIE'; column does
>   not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.    at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:368)
>   ~[jtds-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]   at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2820)
>   ~[jtds-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]   at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2258)
>   ~[jtds-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]   at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:632)
>   ~[jtds-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]   at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.processResults(JtdsStatement.java:584)
>   ~[jtds-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]   at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQL(JtdsStatement.java:546)
>   ~[jtds-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]   at
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:506)
>   ~[jtds-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3421)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3283)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3695)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:149)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]   at
>   java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[?:?]    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:108)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1344)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:435)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3221)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2389)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]   at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:534)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]     ... 98 more

Note that **IS_SUPPRIMER** column is among auditing fields that indicates if this column is deleted or not (IS_SUPPRIMER=true /deleted, IS_SUPPRIMER=false/ not deleted),as result we make a logical remove and not a physical remove.

What's strange here is that the **client** entity which is mapped to **TF_CLIENT** table has a column named **IS_SUPPRIMER** with default value, below the script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TF_CLIENT] (
    [CLT_ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CLT_LIBELLE] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CLT_DT_OUVERTURE] [date] NOT NULL,
    [CLT_DT_FERMETURE] [date],
    [CLT_B_ACTIF] [bit] CONSTRAINT DF_TF_CLIENT_B_ACTIF DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL,
    [DATE_CREATION] [datetime2](3),
    [DATE_MODIFICATION] [datetime2](3),
    [DATE_SUPRESSION] [datetime2](3),
    [AUTEUR_CREATION] [nvarchar](100),
    [AUTEUR_MODIFICATION] [nvarchar](100),
    [AUTEUR_SUPRESSION] [nvarchar](100),
    [IS_SUPPRIMER] [bit] CONSTRAINT DF_TF_UTILISATEUR_IS_SUPPRIMER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT UQ_CLT_LIBELLE UNIQUE(CLT_LIBELLE),
    CONSTRAINT PK_TF_CLIENT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
[CLT_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    END
```

so why updating a such **Client** entity will require a value of **IS_SUPPRIMER** which has already a default value ?

Below the code of Auditing class:

```
@Embeddable
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class FieldAuditing implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "DATE_CREATION")
    private Instant createdAt;

    @Column(name = "DATE_MODIFICATION")
    private Instant updatedAt;

    @Column(name = "DATE_SUPRESSION")
    private Instant deletedAt;

    @Column(name = "AUTEUR_CREATION", length = 100)
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "AUTEUR_MODIFICATION", length = 100)
    private String updatedBy;

    @Column(name = "AUTEUR_SUPRESSION", length = 100)
    private String deletedBy;

    @Column(name = "IS_SUPPRIMER")
    private Boolean isDeleted = false;

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        if (this.isDeleted == null)
            setIsDeleted(Boolean.FALSE);
        setCreatedAt(Instant.now());
        setCreatedBy(LoggedInUser.get());
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void preUpdate() {
        if (this.isDeleted == null)
            setIsDeleted(Boolean.FALSE);
        setUpdatedAt(Instant.now());
        setUpdatedBy(LoggedInUser.get());
    }

}
```

Also the **Client** Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(name="TF_CLIENT", schema="dbo")
public class Client implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8832848102370267801L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator="native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @Column(name = "CLT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "CLT_LIBELLE", nullable = false, length = 50, unique = true)
    private String libelle;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "CLT_DT_OUVERTURE", nullable = false)
    private Date dateOuverture;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "CLT_DT_FERMETURE")
    private Date dateFermeture;

    @Column(name = "CLT_B_ACTIF")
    private boolean isActif;

    @Embedded
    private FieldAuditing fieldAuditing = new FieldAuditing() ;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany
    @Builder.Default
    @JoinColumn(name="CLI_ID")
    Set<Etablissement> etablissements = Collections.emptySet();

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinColumn(name="CLI_ID")
    @Builder.Default
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    Set<CodePaie> codePaies = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "client", orphanRemoval = true)
    @Builder.Default
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    Set<ClientAction> clientActions = Sets.newHashSet();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "client", orphanRemoval = true)
    @Builder.Default
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    Set<ClientEtat> clientEtats = Sets.newHashSet();

    public void addClientActions(Set<ClientAction> clientActions) {
        clientActions.forEach(clientAction -> clientAction.setClient(this));
        this.clientActions.addAll(clientActions);
    }

    public void addClientEtats(Set<ClientEtat> clientEtats) {
        clientEtats.forEach(etat -> etat.setClient(this));
        this.clientEtats.addAll(clientEtats);
    }

    public void addCodePaies(Set<CodePaie> codePaies) {
        codePaies.forEach(codePaie -> codePaie.setClient(this));
        this.codePaies.addAll(codePaies);
    }

    public void removeAllCodePaie() {
        codePaies.forEach(codePaie -> codePaie.setClient(null));
        this.codePaies.clear();
    }

}
```

Finally the code snippet of updating **Client** entity:

```
 private ClientDto save(ClientDto clientDto, Client client) {
        startDateShouldBeBeforeEndDate(clientDto);
        hasUniqueCodePaies(clientDto.getCodePaies());
        Client clientSaved = clientRepository.save(clientMapper.toEntity(clientDto, client));
        clientMapper.addOrRemoveClientActions(clientDto, clientSaved);
        clientMapper.addOrRemoveClientEtats(clientDto, clientSaved);
        clientRepository.save(clientSaved);
        clientDto.setId(clientSaved.getId());
        return clientDto;
    }
```

Kindly, could you take a look at my issue description and help me.

I'm thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The exception indicates that the problem lies in TF_CODE_PAIE not TF_CLIENT. I would guess that TF_CODE_PAIE.IS_SUPPRIMER does not have a default value.

Answer (score 0):

JPA execute query with all field of table. So, when you don't set `isDeleted` field then it null and JPA execute query with null value for `isDeleted` field that's why you got the error.

That's means you are trying to set null value in not-null field which is wrong. Default means when you don't set the field in sql query it set by default value.
Use this

```
@Column(name = "IS_SUPPRIMER", columnDefinition = "bit default 0")
private Boolean isDeleted;
```